# Как создать recyrclerview внутри фрагмента?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

код фрагмента

```
package com.example.reader

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.reader.databinding.FragmentLibraryBinding

class LibraryFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLibraryBinding
    private val adapter = BookAdapter()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentLibraryBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        init()
    }

    private fun init() = with(binding) {
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        recyclerview.adapter = adapter

        val book = Book(1, "hjk")
        adapter.addBook(book)
    }



    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = LibraryFragment()
    }
}
```

код адаптера

```
package com.example.reader

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.reader.databinding.BookItemBinding

class BookAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.BookHolder>() {

    private val bookList = ArrayList<Book>()

    class BookHolder(item: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
        private val binding = BookItemBinding.bind(item)
        fun bind(book: Book) = with(binding){
            bookName.text = book.title
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BookHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.book_item, parent, false)
        return BookHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BookHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(bookList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return bookList.size
    }

    fun addBook(book: Book){
        bookList.add(book)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

элемент recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/library_add_book"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LibraryFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

с класс элемента

```
package com.example.reader

data class Book(val bookId: Int, val title: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Перепишите вот эти 2 метода так:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentLibraryBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    return binding?.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    init()
}
```

Плюс, надо занулить ссылку:

```
private var binding: FragmentLibraryBinding? = null

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    binding = null
}
```

Comment: спасибо))))))))

Comment: Если ответ вам помог - вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)